# importing oracle schema

Tags: oracle, backup, datapump

I need to import a saved .dmp made with exp in Oracle9i in another server which is a copy of the server where the save was made, the save is from a specific scheme (`PERCON`) that is the one I want to import in the other server, I am using exp/imp Well it is an Oracle 9i the export command is:

```
exp system/ssss CONSISTENT=y OWNER=PERCON 
FILE=/backup_exp/export_PERCON.dmp log=/backup_exp/export_PERCON.log BUFFER=30720
```

I would like to know how to import into the copy server since I understand that the method exp launch several errors, is it better to delete the `PERCON` schema on the copy server before the import? Thank you very much.

Comment: Both are 9i, but I understand that the imp gives dependency problems true? I have always used expdp and now I have the doubt that I pose with imp.

Comment: "I understand that the method exp launch several errors,"  What errors?  And don't you mean '_imp_ launch several errors'?  Have you checked the Utilities Guide and reviewed ALL of the parameters for imp, to see any that might address these unknown (to us) errors?

Comment: Importing costs you nothing (much). If there's PERCON schema in the target database and you can drop it whenever you want, simply do the import. Review the log file to see what errors you get, and then you'll know whether you do (or do not) have to do anything about it. If you're highly unsatisfied with the result, drop the user, create it, modify import parameters (according to log info) and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to import a complete schema to the database would be to drop the existing user/schema beforehand.

A simple:

```
drop user percon cascade;
```

...should be enough to have all objects that are related to your schema `percon` to be dropped before you continue with the import.

When you run the import you could just define the schema to import as suggested in a comment:

```
imp fromuser=percon touser=percon file=yourdump.dmp log=imp_percon.log
```

This should import all relevant `percon` schema/user data. If any errors occur you will find them in the log file.